# How to change stack pointer of current thread to new thread in x86 assembly

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, assembly, x86

I am trying to create user level thread library. I have a function called 
`void switch_thread(tcb* currSp,tcb* newSp)` which is implemented in C. `tcb* currSp`,`tcb* newSp` are  stack pointers of current thread and new thread. `switch_thread` function should be implemented in x86 assembly.
My problem is how should I change stack pointer current thread to new thread in x86 assembly.

```
    .text
    .global switch_thread
   switch_thread:
        mov 0x4(%esp), %eax #current thread
        mov 0x8(%esp), %ecx #new thread
            //no idea how to implement rest of it.
```

Comment: Modifying esp is simple. It's everything else that is hard. Do you want help modifying esp? It looks like you already know how to do that. Or do you want help with everything else?

Comment: Give me a any hint about rest of implementation .

Comment: That's not how works here. SO is for specific questions.

Comment: Yes .I though was first  push caller saved registers and then store the sp back to the current sp,When I tried to do that every time I got a segmentation fault.please help on this stage that enough..

Comment: Wots the problem?  Be safe - push everything, including flags, to make an interrupt stack frame at the yop. Store the stack pointer in your 'outgoing' TCB, load in the new SP from your 'incoming' TCB, pop all but interrupt frame, IRET.  Easiest way.

Comment: Why not use an existing stack switching library? No point reinventing the wheel. [There are many to choose from](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3184?page=0,1). That way you can focus on your business logic instead of debugging your threading library. (For example, you're going to run into trouble once you start using the C runtime library.)

Comment: No this our project and try to understand how actually user thread work. and switching part can't implement in c .That is way we try to do it in assembly.

Comment: How is switch thread getting invoked? Normally it occurs due to some call to the operating system (like setting a signal that a thread is waiting for), from another thread or from an interrupt. There should be a structure for each thread, containing a copy of that threads esp, thread priority, ... . Before doing the context switch, the current threads state must be saved on the stack, and the state saved on the stack needs to be done in the same manner for all threads being switched from.

Comment: Don't be surprised if it couldn't be done in pure C with `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`. Also don't be surprised if this has been implemented on most OSs and discarded because kernel threads were better.

Comment: @rcgldr: The typical idea is to have "blocking" library functions that are wrappers for non-blocking system calls. Also note that "Thread priority within process" can work, but "thread priority within system" can't work without kernel. Finally, for sane behaviour under multiple CPUs you need N kernel threads mapped to M user-threads, and it ends up being a massive pain.

Comment: Yes .I have been using round robing method to schedule it .No special method to set priority of thread. and                                                           struct tcb { 
  void* sp; 
  int id;     
}; used to save thread details.

Comment: @Brendan - yeah, and almost certainly a buggy, massive pain.  It's like reinventing the kernel, probably badly.

Comment: Since you say that this is a school project: Is it allowed by the project rules to ask for help from outsiders? (Presumably you at least have to credit any outside help in your write-up.) [This CS class](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~chris/teaching/cs170/projects/proj2.html) managed to use longjmp to do the actual stack switching. I reiterate that stack switching is the least of your problems.

Comment: @user1574779 - "round robin". So does each thread make a call to some operating system function to allow other threads to run if that thread is cpu bound and not waiting for some type of signal? Assuming all context switches are effectively returns from calls to operating system functions, then when calling those operating system functions, the context of that thread needs to be saved before switching to another thread.

Comment: @rcgldr this is the part I am going to switch thread each other.All other things are done by C.If you have any idea please share with me.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, the call would used code similar to getcontext(), but it would be pushing the all values on to the stack, then save the stack pointer in the thread control block structure. When doing a context switch, the dispatcher would be similar to setcontext(), except it would be popping values from the stack, ending with a return to continue running the switched to thread.

Comment: Your question was about how to change the stack pointer. In your comments you seem to be confusing this with *preemption*. They are not the same thing. Please do research about *preemption*, and then if you still have questions, ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The functions in `<ucontext.h>` do exactly this, and [`setcontext()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) is what you want in particular. This function is implemented in GLIBC, and [the source file for it](http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/setcontext.S) can be found in various places on the internet.

Casually looking over the assembly, it basically recovers the floating point context, and then  recovers all the other registers.